# Where does the python logging module write to, inside an Ansible module?

Tags: python, ansible

When I run the ansible dnf module, the messages dnf writes through the `logging` module do not appear to go *anywhere*.  Why does this happen?

---

I have a call chain something like:

ansible (python3) -> ansible dnf module -> `import dnf` ... -> dnf plugin etckeeper-dnf

The current version of etckeeper-dnf goes on to run `etckeeper`, using `os.system()`.  So it writes to stdout and [confuses ansible](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511210/ansible-dnf-module-module-failure).  I assume this is an error in etckeeper-dnf.  I am fairly confident that ansible is allowed to `import dnf` etc.  I came across another fix for a dnf plugin that says the dnf `cli` objects are not necessarily available, which sounds like a similar scenario.

It seems reasonable for Ansible to want to be able to control stdout/stderr, and not have them interfered with by library code.

So I have patched etckeeper-dnf and I am effectively piping it's stdout+stderr to the python `logging` module.  This does exactly what I wanted.  It fixes Ansible.  And the `dnf` command still shows all the etckeeper messages.  (They are also now copied to `/var/log/dnf.log`).

**But now I have a reading comprehension problem.**

When I run the ansible dnf module, the messages dnf writes through the `logging` module,  including from etckeeper-dnf, do not appear to go *anywhere*.

That's not my change, not my fault, and it's not something I need.  I even tested what would happen if etckeeper fails: etckeeper-dnf just continues, so Ansible wouldn't show any warnings about it anyway (unless I deliberately broke Ansible).

But I can't help but feel uncomfortable about the idea that any warning messages are going to be lost.

I made sure to test using `dnfpluginscore.logger.error()`, as well as `.info()`, but I don't see the messages in either case.

The default configuration of the `logging` module is to write to stderr.  The `dnf` module does not do anything to configure it, unless you use `dnf.cli.BaseCli`.  The Ansible module `dnf.py` does not use anything from `dnf.cli`, and does not do anything with `logging`.  The base class `AnsibleModule` does not use python `logging` either; it has its own independent `.log()` method.

So why do the messages written with `.error()` not appear on the Ansible module output pipe, and break Ansible again?

- ansible-2.7.10-1.fc29.noarch
- dnf-4.2.2-2.fc29.noarch
- python3-3.7.3-1.fc29.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original `etckeeper-dnf` broke Ansible because it wrote to stdout.  Whereas we determined that the python `logging` module writes to stderr.

If you look at the output in the link, Ansible separates `module_stdout` and `module_stderr`.  Usually it just ignores `module_stderr`; it only shows it in case of `MODULE FAILURE`.  (Although some other modules do not always separate stdout/stderr, [e.g. the Ansible `script` module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/14960)).

So I still think the proposed change in etckeeper-dnf is reasonable.  And regardless of how *deliberately* the Ansible dnf module was designed this way, it seems fairly reasonable to rely on this specific behaviour.  The changed code is unlikely to be broken by future changes in the Ansible dnf module.

I would note that when you hit a `MODULE FAILURE`, `module_stderr` only shows dnf's error messages.  You do not see any messages from loglevel INFO or below, i.e. dnf's usual non-error, non-interactive output.

(*If* etckeeper failures were treated as fatal when using etckeeper-dnf, then it might not be a great idea to log all the etckeeper output using `.info()`.  Ansible would miss the original error messages from etckeeper (and the error messages would not be logged anywhere else).

However, I tested the system after hacking etckeeper to return `EXIT_FAILURE`.  IIRC, dnf continued regardless of any etckeeper failure.  The overall effect is that Ansible will not give you *any* information about the failure to run etckeeper, regardless of how I log errors.  And in general, treating `stdout` and `stderr` messages separately is more complex and does weird things to the order of messages.  So I followed the K.I.S.S. principle :-).

---

Or to put it more generally:

As per default, `logging` messages written at loglevel INFO and below will go nowhere.  Messages at loglevel WARNING and above will go to stderr.  They will not interfere with normal Ansible module operation.  In normal Ansible module operation, even these messages will not go anywhere.

If there is a `MODULE FAILURE` - i.e. the module crashes or does not generate JSON output that Ansible can parse as expected - Ansible will show `module_stderr`, which includes `logging` messages at or above loglevel WARNING only.